# Read O365 protected mails from EWS?

Tags: encryption, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We have a service service that interacts with users via email.  We are using Exchange Web Services to send and ingest email.  We have a few mail responses that are being received as protected such as:

> Fictitious User (fict@example.com) has sent you a protected message.
>   Learn about messages protected by Office 365 Message Encryption.
>   Privacy Statement
>   Email encryption powered by Office 365. Learn More

Is it possible to read the contents of the protected message via EWS?

Answer (score 0):

No EWS doesn't provide any operations or interfaces to decode a Rights protected Email. Generally RMS messages are .rpmsg which are rights protected msg files which are an office file format. There are RMS SDK's which have library that can decode the content in the correct environments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/develop/active-directory-rights-management-services-multi-platform-thin-client-sdk-portal .